# Storing image as base64string (varchar(max)) or varbinary

Tags: sql

What are the pro's and con's of each?

My requirements are:

1. I want to be able to encrypt the image
2. Easily accessible on a mobile device through a webserver (RESTful API)
3. Easily accessible on a mobile device through a local database like SQLLite

The databases im using on the server side is MS SQL 2005.
I beleive SQLLite and MS SQL 2005 can support both varchar and varbinary (BLOB on sqllite)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing image in database directly or as base64 data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 only uses 6 out of 8 bits in a byte.  It dates back to the time when emails were transmitted over lines that were not 7 bits safe.

Back then, you'd store the image as a binary blob, because that required 33% less storage space.  Then you'd convert it on the fly when a client requests a `base64` encoded string.  Conversion to base64 is very cheap.

That still makes sense today-- store it as a `binary`, transmit it like whatever the client requests.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I will now just need to check out the feasibility of encryping this binary data.

Comment: @Andomar, what are the cons of storing the images as varchar(max) in the sql server database.  There is no need for encryption here.  I am already doing this and transmitting to the client as a 'string' via c#.