# storing image in database is bad idea then what is the alternatives?

Tags: android

I read many stack overflow posts saying that inserting images in database is bad

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) and [Storing image in database directly or as base64 data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) and many others.

the thing is still not obvious for me **where to save the image ? in a file in server** ?. in my application the user will upload several images and see them in his profile.

an example will be much appreciate.

what I did for now ( I now its not that good but I am learning..)

```
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);          
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);


            //fnish inserting
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emails));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));

            System.out.println(nameValuePairs);
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://justedhak.comlu.com/users.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println(response);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If your images weigh(2KB-4KB) you can save in DB

If your images exceed this weight i recommend use SD card.

Comment: If the are many users posted  images in the application.. where should i save the image ?

Comment: Like Fb or Tw? or you know and example similar to your app?

Comment: Yes like fb and what do u mean by example of my app