# Insert image to vaadin grid

Tags: java, image, resources, blob, vaadin

*How to show images (**blob type**) into vaadin grid ?*

*Is there any good example ?*

*How to define right class for coloumns that will hold blob (i store my images as blob in mysql) type image in vaadin grid ?*
**I also want to show default picture (user_pic.jpg) in vaadin grid from resources ("/WEB-INF/images/user_pic.jpg") if user doesn't have picture.**

**PSEUDO CODE:**

```
if (user have picture)
  show his picture in grid
else 
 show default picture from resources
```

Comment: If you saw the previous version of my answer, take a look at the updated one. I figured a _hack_ which should allow you to use the current ImageRenderer with ExternalResource **if** you can [save your images as base64 strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) at the cost of some bandwith & maybe load time, depending on your usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM:**

I used **table** instead *grid*. Here is my code for emdadding pictures into table:

```
        Person tr = tap.get(i);

        Embedded emb=new Embedded("myembeddedimage");

        StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

            public InputStream getStream() {
                 //get blob inputstream
                 return new ByteArrayInputStream(tr.getPicture());
            }

         };
       //create StreamResource from blob inputstream and name it.
       StreamResource sourceone=new StreamResource(source, "mypicture.png");
       sourceone.setCacheTime(0l); 
       emb.setHeight("200px");
       emb.setWidth("150px");
       //if user doesn't have image, the embedded image source is set to image from resource
       emb.setSource(tr.getPicture()==null? new ThemeResource("images/user_pic.jpg"): sourceone);

       CheckBox checkbox=new CheckBox();
        checkbox.setConvertedValue(false);

       tPartners.addItem((new Object[] {emb,
                (tr.getName() +" "+ tr.getSurname()), -2,checkbox}),tr);
```

I hope someone will find this code useful. This code is good example how to insert image into table if you have your image (as blob for example) stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

> I also want to show default picture (user_pic.jpg) in vaadin grid from resources ("/WEB-INF/images/user_pic.jpg") if user doesn't have picture.

This should be easily doable by using the [`ImageRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) shipped with Vaadin using a [`ThemeResource`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-resources.html), but you may need to move your image under your theme directory instead: `webapp/VAADIN/themes/your_theme/images`

---

**2)**

> How to show images (blob type) into vaadin grid ?

As far as I know there isn't (yet) a built-in renderer that can do what you need, which seems to be confirmed by [this question in the Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9713833). So far the [`ImageRenderer` sources](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/ImageRenderer.java) indicate that it only supports either `ExternalResource` or `ThemeResource`:

```
@Override
    public JsonValue encode(Resource resource) {
        if (!(resource == null || resource instanceof ExternalResource || resource instanceof ThemeResource)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "ImageRenderer only supports ExternalResource and ThemeResource ("
                            + resource.getClass().getSimpleName() + " given)");
        }
```

You will probably have to implement your own renderer. [Here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientsidewidgets/clientsidewidgets-grid.html#clientsidewidgets.grid.renderers) and [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9418390/9765924) you might find a starting point. And btw, if you do decide to write your implementation, please consider sharing it with the rest of the world, I'm sure a lot of people would benefit from it :-)

---

**Later edit:**

I just thought of a *hack* you can use with the standard ImageRenderer. If you can store your images encoded as base64 strings then you can wrap them in a ExternalResource doing something like this:

```java
public static class MyBean {
    private ExternalResource image;
    private String name, surname;

    public MyBean(ExternalResource image, String name, String surname) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public ExternalResource getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyGridComponent extends VerticalLayout {
    public MyGridComponent() {
        BeanItemContainer<MyBean> dataSource = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class);
        Grid grid = new Grid(dataSource);
        addComponent(grid);


        grid.getColumn("image").setRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
        grid.setColumnOrder("image", "name", "surname");

        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(
                new ExternalResource("data:image/png;base64,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"),
                "Agent",
                "Smith"));
        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(
                new ExternalResource("data:image/jpeg;base64,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"),
                "There is",
                "No spoon"));
        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(
                new ExternalResource("data:image/jpeg;base64,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"),
                "The",
                "One"));
    }
}
```

Which should get you something similar to:

[image: Demo]