# Storing and Retrieving Image Data URL

Tags: javascript, sql, image

Is it possible to store 'Data URL' extracted from a canvas by `toDataURL("image/png");` in a database and reconstruct the image by retrieving this 'Data URL'? I have tried to store the 'data URL' to a `BLOB`.

Answer (score 2):

`toDataURL("image/png")` method returns a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) only. You can store that to sql database easily and the same can be retrieved and used to construct the image. You will have to set the `src` of the image with the retrieved data URI. Please refer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) also, this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all you want to make, but here is a little example of the process I used.

First convert the canvas to an imageUrl with canvas.toDataURL() which returns a DataURL of the canvas in .png format.

**Client:**

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PHPfile.php",
  data: {
     image: dataURL
  }
})
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=XXXX;dbname=YYY', "ZZZ", "1234");

    $insert="insert into designs(image) values(:image)";        
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
    $stmt->bindValue(":image",$_POST["image"]);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Now you have the image stored on your DB.