# Best way to store base64 string in HANA Cloud Database? (HANA MDC<trial>)

Tags: ios, database, swift3

​As the title states, what is the best way to store a base64 string on the HANA Cloud database? I've been using a BLOB column type to store them, but the OData of my database displays it as a SAP ODATA defined "edm.binary" value, and I can't seem to insert more images into the database from my iOS app due to that fact, as I cant find a way to convert a base64 string into binary value

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not really related to HANA in my opinion, but it is a more general database question. See [Storing image in database directly or as base64 data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data).

In general, you either store it base64 = string or you store it binary = blob. You should not mix it (both base64 and binary), because it is both reduntant and you have the worst out of both worlds (both difficult to represent it into a plain text representation and also larger size).

To answer your original question, I would strongly NOT recommend you to store a base64 in a blob. As base64 is a simple string, you can use either of the character types, based on how large you expect it to be. See [Character String Types](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/a33f7884b0c14c00b1a76ecd8af5feca.html) (smaller ones, most likely not a fit for your needs) and [Large Object types](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/c374aca91944460b834ef1d5ceb82acf.html). My recommendation would be to use CLOB (as base64 is ASCII and you don't need full-text search support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding LOBs! Ok so I've decided to use CLOB to store my base64 string, but my OData still treats it as a Edm.Binary value, is this behavior normal?