# Converting image to base64 in react native

Tags: react-native, file-upload, expo

I just start to learning how to upload image on react native with expo and I have successfully log my image file to the console which means its ready to be uploaded on the server, but I heard about base64, and I don't really get the concept of that... do I need to convert my image to base64 before uploading to the server or image will be converted to base64 when requested from the server? Can somebody enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can review [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) to understand the base64 concept, its advantages, disadvantages and the basic idea behind it.